# Why does foreach skip compile time type checking on interface types?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, foreach, static-typing

When I use a `foreach` loop in C#, it appears that no compile time type checking is performed if the item type is an interface type.

E.g.

```
class SomeClass {}
interface SomeInterface {}

IEnumerable<SomeClass> stuff;
foreach(SomeInterface obj in stuff) { // This compiles - why!?
}
```

This will happily compile and cause an exception at runtime, when it is clear at compile time this makes no sense.  If I change the item type from `SomeInterface` to another class, then compile time type-checking is restored:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> stuff;
foreach(Random obj in stuff) { // This doesn't compile - good!
}
```

Why is there no compile time type checks when the item type is an interface?

(This occurs with .NET 3.5 SP1 in Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: Yeah, I've wondered about (and been bitten by) the same thing. Looking forward to the answers from those in the know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is NOT clear at compile time whether another part of the program, maybe in a different project, has:

```
class SomeOtherClass : SomeClass, ISomeInterface
{
   public static IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetSomeStuff()
   {
      for( int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
         yield return new SomeOtherClass(i);
   }
}
```

Now the runtime check SUCCEEDS.

If you mark `SomeClass` as `sealed` then this isn't possible, and it's again possible to know at compile time that the cast will never work.

Comment: What you say is correct.  I am surprised that C# takes this approach with "foreach" as it makes the language inconsistent.  Method calls don't have this same behaviour for example.

Comment: It's not inconsistent, it's the same behavior as casting, consider: `foreach (SomeClass obj in stuff) ((ISomeInterface)obj).SomeInterfaceMethod();`

Comment: It's just suprising (to me) that foreach is effectively doing a hidden dynamic cast.  Other things like variable assignments ("a = b;") or function calls ("myFunc(c);") don't silently perform dynamic casts.

Dynamic casts (IMHO) should be clear and obvious in the code.

Comment: Another reason I should properly seal my classes.