# foreach won't type check even when enumerated type is sealed

Tags: c#, foreach, typechecking

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389327/why-does-foreach-skip-compile-time-type-checking-on-interface-types). But instead my `SomeClass` implements `SomeInterface`. In this case, even if I mark `SomeClass` as `sealed`, compiler time type check still don't kick in. Example below.

#### Question 1: Why wouldn't the compiler give an error as the type of the loop variable isn't compatible with the type of elements of the source enumerable?

Having compiler type check is important to me, as I'm refactoring a big project, changing the enumeration source (`source` in a `foreach (SomeClass foo in source)`) from `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` to `IEnumerable<SomeInterface>`. Sometime I forget to change the enumerator type declaration in the loop from `SomeClass` to `SomeInterface`, and the project still compiles. That would break things really bad!!

#### Question 2: What suggestion do you have to make this refactoring type safe?

Note that I can't change loop variable type to be implicit `var` because it's exiting code base. But I am able to change the declaration of the interface and its concrete implementation classes.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<SomeInterface> someFoos = new SomeInterface[] { new SomeOtherClass(), new SomeOtherClass(), new SomeOtherClass() };
        foreach (SomeClass foo in someFoos)
        {
            foo.ToString(); // runtime InvalidCastException
        }
    }
}

interface SomeInterface { }

sealed class SomeClass : SomeInterface
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "SomeClass";
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass : SomeInterface
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "SomeOtherClass";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `var` instead of a specific type in your `foreach` loop (i.e. `foreach (var foo in someFoos)`). The compiler will then infer the type of `foo` from the type of `someFoos`.

Comment: @CraigW. this is an existing project that I don't have that control. Plus whether to use `var` or the specific type is debatable.

Comment: If you don't have control over the syntax of the loop then there's really nothing you can do.

Comment: This is just the way that C# works - `foreach` comes with an implicit cast. So long as the cast is *potentially* valid (as it is here) it will compile with no problems. It's not clear what sort of answer you're looking for really.

Comment: There is no way to make this compile-time safe. The best you could do is either use `SomeInterface` in your `foreach` loop or filter `someFoos` so that only instances of `SomeClass` are returned via `OfType`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated my question to contain two questions. Do you think that clarifies things a little?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're specifically calling out the fact that it is a sealed class.  Sealed simply means that the class can't be extended in a `public class Whatever : SomeClass` respect, it shouldn't (at least in my limited knowledge) have any impact on iteration.  Am I just looking to far into the fact that it was called out 2 or 3 times?

Comment: Your first question still isn't clear - are you asking why C# was designed in this way, or which C# rules are allowing this? Your second question feels like the answer is mostly "the same way as anything else you can't check at compile time - careful review and unit tests..."

Comment: @Kritner:  It's additional information from which a sufficiently advanced compiler "should" be able to determine that instances of that type don't have any unknown type information.  In this case, I think it doesn't ultimately help, because the `IEnumerable`'s type information doesn't even know it contains that particular element type.

Comment: Wait... @CraigW.said to change in your foreach `type` to `var` but you said you don't have control over the code (or am I misunderstanding that?)... so what is it you're changing around when mentioning changing `SomeClass` to `SomeInterface` it sounds like you're changing the enumeration type?

Comment: @JonSkeet, my first question is why wouldn't compiler give an error that the type of the loop variable isn't compatible with what you can get out of the source enumerable.

Comment: You haven't explained what kind of "why" though. Please reread my previous comment.

Answer (score 8):

You have asked two questions in one question. As almost always happens, you've had one of your two questions answered. In the future, consider asking one question per question; you are more likely to have your question answered.

I'll answer your first question.

> Question 1: Why wouldn't the compiler give an error as the type of the loop variable isn't compatible with the type of elements of the source enumerable?

This is a "why not" question, and it is very difficult to give answers to "why not" questions; they presuppose that the world ought to be a different way and ask why it isn't. There are literally an infinite number of reasons why the world isn't the way you want it to be. My advice is that you stop asking "why not?" questions here. Instead, try asking questions about *how the world is*.

So let me clarify the question. We have

```
foreach(X item in collection)
```

where `collection` is a sequence of `Y`.

> Question: what must the relationship between `X` and `Y` be?

`Y` must be *explicitly* convertible to `X`. That is, a cast operator of the form `(X)` must be legal to apply to an item of type `Y`.

This is one of the rare situations in which C# will automatically insert a cast operation on your behalf without a cast operator being manifest in the code.

> Question: What language design principles suggest that this situation ought to be rare?

C# is designed to be a statically-checked type-safe language; this conversion moves the type check to runtime rather than compile-time, decreasing safety.

> Question: Language design decisions require making tradeoffs between competing principles. What was the compelling scenario that caused the C# design team to include an "invisible" cast in the language?

The semantics of the `foreach` loop were developed before generics were added to the language. This means that it was likely that a sequence would be `IEnumerable`, and therefore would be a sequence of `object`s.  But the user likely has knowledge that a particular sequence is, say, all strings.  Therefore, in C# 1.0, this code would be extremely common:

```
foreach(object item in collection)
{
    string s = (string)item;
    ...
```

Which seems needlessly verbose. Therefore the language design team decided to allow the conversion to the loop variable type to be explicit.

One might reasonably note that this adds the potential for bugs that you've discovered. An alternative feature might be to say that the conversion only happens if converting from `object`. There are possibly other design choices that could have been made. The C# design team chose to make the conversion explicit and that's what we've got to live with.

In a counterfactual world where generic collections were available from day one, the design would likely be different. But that sort of counterfactual reasoning isn't really very productive.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question:

> Question 2: What suggestion do you have to make this refactoring type safe?

The refactoring you are describing is *not* type safe! The contract was "I'll give you a sequence of mammals", and the code that consumes this contractual obligation quite reasonably assumes that everything in there is going to produce milk, give birth to live young, and grow hair.  (Leaving aside the monotremes.)  You are changing that contract to "actually, I'll give you a sequence of animals", and there could be a squid or a lizard in there now.  You are *weakening* a contract, and that's always dangerous. You need to get buy-in from all the parties to that contract before you weaken it,.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, which would should be perfectly safe:

```
foreach (SomeClass foo in someFoos.Where(foo => foo is SomeClass))
{
    // Do something specific with a SomeClass type here
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't need to do something that is specific to SomeClass, then just use the interface in your loop:

```
foreach (SomeInterface foo in someFoos)
{
    // Do something with SomeInterface properties or methods here
}
```

Comment: That's really not my goal. Yes this will make the program not to throw, but it's logically wrong as you're not enumerating the entire collection, while the foreach loop is refactored to really enumerate through the abstracted instances which potentially have different implementations.

Comment: I would argue that it's logically wrong to expect all instances of an interface to be of a specific type. The second example will loop through everything, but you won't be able to call properties/methods that are specific to the `SomeClass` type.

Comment: Side note: `.OfType<SomeClass>()` is designed for this use case, but that doesn't resolve any of the other issues raised.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you can't change the loop but you can change the classes, then another possibility would be to un-seal `SomeClass` and have `SomeOtherClass` inherit from `SomeClass`. This will allow your existing loop to work as well:

```
interface SomeInterface { }

class SomeClass : SomeInterface
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "SomeClass";
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass : SomeClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "SomeOtherClass";
    }
}
```